# VIDIOC_REQBUFS Error 12 when opening multiple v4l2 sources

Tags: video-capture, nvidia, ioctl, v4l2, v4l

I'm using an 8-channel PCI-based framegrabber on Nvidia TX1 dev kit. I'm using [this driver](https://github.com/FrankBau/tw6869) along with it. I can play up to 3/4 v4l2 camera feeds comfortably using mplayer, streamer or VLC but I always get a memory allocation error when I start playing the 5th camera feed, irrespective of the software I use to play it. I also wrote my own program to capture and display v4l2 streams but I'm getting the same problem. The exact error is  an `error 12` given by the ioctl command:

`ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &req)`

I have tried this framegrabber and device on a standalone PC and it works perfectly fine.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it running my changing the CONFIG_CMA_SIZE_MBYTES variable from 16 to 32 while building the kernel.